How to reduce indexing rate of bots
Some bots such as claudebot slow down our servers by indexing content with a high rate of request per sec.
I don't want to ban them. I'm looking for a way to slow down them with apache.
I tried using ratelimit like this :
<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} =~ /claudebot/">
     <Limit GET POST>
        SetOutputFilter RATE_LIMIT
        SetEnv rate-limit 10
        SetEnv rate-limit-burst 5
        SetEnv rate-limit-delay 500
    </Limit>
</If>  

But it seems inefficient.
I found way with libapache2-mod-evasive with prevent from DOS attack and can block IP if rate is higher.
Is it possible to activate mod-evasive for specified user-agent?

It's not the indexing part that affects you, it's the scraping part. I believe mod_ratelimit limits bandwidth not resource usage - by artificially throttling the traffic your are making each request longer and therefore compounding the impact on your server.
If it were me, and assuming that the objective here is to still allow crawling but limit rate only, I'd use fail2ban to detect high bot traffic, and some mechanism to switch to an HTTP endpoint that responds with a 429 when thresholds are breached.
(some mechanism could be an iptables redirect to a vhost running on a different port, or a .htaccess file defining behaviour for a setp of iP addresses, for example).
